# ios uiWebView: jplayer plays mp3 in simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xcode6, jplayer

I created a simple app in Xcode 6 which wraps a uiWebView object to render the contents of a website. The website includes mp3s which sometime play automatically on load, using jplayer. I've set allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES and mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO.

When I run the app through the simulator (xcode 6/iPad2/ios8) the sound plays fine. When I run the app through my iPad (8.1.2) the sound doesn't play, even in the cases where it's triggered by a user action. I've checked the mute button and volume controls. I've also checked the paths to the mp3s for case and it all looks ok.

Any ideas why this is working on the simulator but not the iPad?